# Multiples Handlers Trigger

Tags: handler

My app records field elements to help mappers design Orienteering maps, using a cell phone GPS. A Waypoint or Trackway is saved using .gpx format and recording´s pace can be adjusted from 2 to 6 seconds @ Preference.

The check is performed by comparing a phone´s time window against a satellite one using a post delay handler. Satellite signal is checked once each 8 times of the record interval. It is started onResume only and asked to stop onPause. Before start it, there is a call to kill any handler in place. The handler also waits 30 seconds for signal stabilization.

For reasons not identified, sometimes more than one handler is active at the same time, what causes the signal test to fail since the satelite time value becomes smaller than phone´s one. I can force the issue to (sometimes) appears if I go to the Preference and come back to the main aplication within less than the time window (8 X recording interval).

Toast messages and r are for debug purpose only.

What I am doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    // ...
    //
    //Set the timers that will supervise the GPS signal activity
    /*
     * Compare timers to see if the satellites still visible within a time window
     */
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    mPhoneActualTime = currentTime.getTime();
    mPhonePreviousTime = mPhoneActualTime;

    Toast.makeText(Oribooklet.this,"Kill - RESUME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    checkGPS();
}
//
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(Oribooklet.this,"Kill - PAUSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
//
// A Handler is responsible to check if we loose the satellites
// Start 30 seconds after GPS is on to allow stabilization.
// Check every 8 GPS data update to not overload
public void checkGPS() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Toast.makeText(Oribooklet.this, "Trigger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    handler.postDelayed(checkGPSSignalLoss, 30 * 1000);
}

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int r;

private Runnable checkGPSSignalLoss = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        mPhoneActualTime = currentTime.getTime();
        // Use 70% as a GPS communication error of real time
        long phoneTimeDifference = (long) (0.7 * (mPhoneActualTime - mPhonePreviousTime));
        long gpsTimeDifference = mGPSActualTime - mGPSPreviousTime;
        mPhonePreviousTime = mPhoneActualTime;
        mGPSPreviousTime = mGPSActualTime;

        ++r;
        Toast.makeText(Oribooklet.this, gpsTimeDifference + " " +
                        phoneTimeDifference + " - " +
                        String.valueOf(r)
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Check the time difference between the 2 GPS recordings above
        // It must be at least 10% higher than real time, if not, the satellites are gone!
        if (gpsTimeDifference < phoneTimeDifference ){
            // Change UI
            String textGPS = getResources().getString(R.string.waiting);
            TextView textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSatellites);

            // Set a turning progress bar and a message to feedback the loss
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
            textOut.setText(textGPS);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Check every 8X the GPS communication interval
        handler.postDelayed(this, lTimerToUpdateGPS);
    }
};
```

Comment: You forgot to state what language this is in your question and the tags. I mean, we can see what it (most likely) is, but using correct tags keeps the place nice and tidy.

Comment: To be honest I did. I put android and handler. I do not know why is not there.